# Swift protocol conformance with sub type

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I would like to be able to implement a property of a protocol (B below) using a type that implements the requirements of the protocol. e.g. I want to get the code below to compile. At the moment, the error is "Type D does not conform to protocol B"

```
protocol A {
   func doSomething()
}

protocol B {
    var property: A { get }
}

class C: A {
    func doSomething() {
        //Stuff
    }
}

class D: B {
    var property: C = C()
}
```

Comment: guess swift isnt that good in that respect: ```var property: A = C()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess this should be done with associated types

```
protocol B {
    associatedtype T : A
    var property: T { get }
}

class D : B{
    var property : C = C()

}
```

Comment: This works but it seems I simplified my example to far. D's property C is actually a protocol X  which inherits from A that C implements. var property : X = C()